# Why did Ravana abduct Sita?

Tags: ramayana

Which of the following was the most important reason for Ravana abducting Sita?

1. Because *Suparnakha* was humiliated whatever was the reason
2. Because he came to know that Sita was the most beautiful women in the world so she could be the his wife.
3. Because *Khara* & *Dusana* were killed by Lord Rama & Lord Laxmana and it was the duty of the King to take revenge . it is immaterial for Ravana that "Khar & Dusan were killed as they attacked for wrong reasons"
4. No one can show supremacy in front of Ravana even if he's right.

[Can anyone tell me the actual reason?](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070820222217AAcTHn1)

Comment: Can you make your question a bit more descriptive? Providing a link and raising a concern isn't helpful, as if the linked page gets changed or get deleted, your question won't be useful anymore and will make it unclear for future visitors of what you are asking specifically..

Comment: There would be no story of the Ramayana without the abduction of Sita!!

Answer (score 4):

There are several reasons

- Ravan was not invited by Raja Janak in Mata Sita's Saymbar
- Ravan want to take revenge of his sister Soorpanaka

  these are the reasons but the main reason is

> According to a story from Bhagavata Purana, the Four Kumaras, Sanaka,
> Sanandana, Sanatana, and Sanatkumara who are the manasaputras of
> Brahma (sons born from the mind or thought power of Brahma), visited
> Vaikuntha, the abode of Vishnu, to see him.
>
> Due to the strength of their tapas, the four Kumaras appear to be mere children, though they are of great age. Jaya and Vijaya, the gate
> keepers of the Vaikuntha interrupt the Kumaras at the gate, thinking
> them to be children. They also tell the Kumaras that Sri Vishnu is
> resting and that they cannot see him now. The enraged Kumaras replied
> Jaya and Vijaya that Vishnu is available for his devotees any time,
> and cursed both the keepers Jaya and Vijaya, that they would have to
> give up their divinity, be born as mortals on Earth (bhuloka, or
> physical plane), and live like normal human beings. Vishnu appeared
> before them, and the gatekeepers requested Vishnu to lift the curse of
> the Kumaras. Vishnu says curse of Kumaras cannot be reversed. Instead,
> he gives Jaya and Vijaya two options.
>
> 1. The first option is to take seven births on Earth as a devotee of Vishnu.
> 2. Second is to take three births as his enemy.
>
> After serving either of these sentences, they can re-attain their stature at Vaikuntha and
> be with him permanently. Jaya and Vijaya cannot bear the thought of
> staying away from Vishnu for seven lives. As a result, they choose to
> be born three times on Earth even though it would have to be as
> enemies of Vishnu. (This story is also used as a metaphor about the
> cost of committing transgressions in "The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna".)
>
> In the first life they were born as Hiranyakashipu and Hiranyaksha in the Krita Yuga, to Diti (daughter of Daksha Prajapathi) and sage
> Kashyapa who were killed by Vishnu taking the form of Varaha, a boar
> and Narasimha,a man-lion in the Satya Yuga.
>
> In their second life they were born as Ravana and Kumbhakarna and were killed by Vishnu who descended as Rama in the Treta Yuga.
>
> And in their third life as Shishupala and Dantavakra (in some places Dantavakra is replaced by Kamsa) who were killed by Vishnu who
> descended as Krishna in the Dwapara Yuga.
>
> It has been noted by many that the strengths of Jaya and Vijaya gradually declined with each subsequent birth. Vishnu needed one
> avatar each to kill Hiranyaksha and Hiranyakashipu. Born as Rama he
> was able to vanquish both Ravana and Kumbhakarna. In his Krishna
> avatar the killing of Shishupala and Danthavakra is not the main focus
> but more to reduce the 'Bhoobhara" (The burden on mother earth by too
> many sinners).

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaya-Vijaya)

So is This the main reason . Everything was preplanned. They just have to follow that.